# Quadratic function of continuous random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ is a continuous random variable that has uniform distribution on $[0,4]$.

What is CDF of $Y=(X-2)^2$?

Attempt: $G_Y(y)=P\left(Y\le y\right)=P\left((X-2)^2\le y\right)=P\left(-\sqrt{y}\le X-2\le \sqrt{y}\right)=P\left(-\sqrt{y}+2\le X\le \sqrt{y}+2\right)=P\left(X\le \sqrt{y}+2\right)-P\left(X\ge -\sqrt{y}+2\right)=F_X\left(\sqrt{y}+2\right)-1+F_X\left(-\sqrt{y}+2\right)$

I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake. $G_Y(y)=F_X(\sqrt y+2)-F_X(-\sqrt y +2)$. In general, $P(a<X\leq b)=F_X(b)-F_X(a)$.

By the definition of uniform distrbution on $[0,4]$ we have $F_X(x)=\frac x 4$ for $0<x\leq 4$, $0$ for $x \leq 0$ and $1$ for $x >4$. Conisder the cases $0<y\leq 4$ and $y >4$ to complete the evaluation.

Answer: $G_Y(Y)=
\frac {\sqrt y} 2$ for $0<y<4$.

Comment: $G_Y(y)=\frac{\sqrt{y}+2}{4}+\frac{-\sqrt{y}+2}{4}-1=0$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, there was  a mistake in your expression for $G_Y(y)$. See my answer now.  @eMathHelp